# How to solve this differential equation??

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Good morning (or evening) to everybody.

I would like to know how may I work to solve this differential equation:

$$\dot{R}^2 = \alpha\dot{r}^2 - \beta\dot{r}^4$$

Where $R$ is $R(t)$ and $r$ is also a function of time. Clearly $r \neq R$.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two real positive coefficients.

Comment: What function do you want to find? $R$ or $r$?

Comment: I want to find R(t)!

Answer (score 1):

Having no more details on $R$ and $r$, and not being able to eliminate $t$, this leaves
$$
R(t) = R(t_0) + \int\limits_{t_0}^t\sqrt{\alpha \dot{r}^2(\hat{t}) + \beta \dot{r}^4(\hat{t})} \, d\hat{t}
$$